# link to framework is always required on each launch

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am facing an annoying behavior when linking some external libraries to my framework project.

When linking the library to my project everything works fine, but when i close the project and re-open the Xcode then launching the project and run it, it gave me an error that the library is not linked in my framework and i should add it(it is already shown in framework). When i re-add it, everything will works fine again.

I don't know if that is considered as a bug or not, but every time i open my application in Xcode, i should add about 5 frameworks in order to run my application which annoys me!

why some libraries(not all externals) are keep asking me to link them to framework??
is there a way that those libraries are added once without keeping annoying me?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: have you added your in build phase - "Link binary with libraries"???

Comment: and next time when you open then whether your framework is present there or not? and have you checked the header search path for this framework? make sure you provide right path??

Comment: How can i check the header search path for the framework?..i add libraries from my application folder by clicking "+" then "Add other" and from the application folder path

Comment: should i add that in the "Header Search path" in Build Settings Tab?

Comment: either put that framework in your app base folder, then you don't need to add the path.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57564/discussion-between-rishi-and-iphone-user).

Comment: I fixed it now as you mentioned but putting them in the base folder  and worked perfectly..you are a genius..Feel free to add it in the answer section to mark it as an answer :) Thank a lot for saving my life from this annoying problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct Header search path of your frameworks. Two ways -

1. Either put framework in your application base folder.
2. Or provide framework path in your header search path.